# SQL Query - Join two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables temp1 & temp2. I have 5 columns (a,b,c,d,e) in temp1 and 5 columns (a,b,c,d,e) in temp2

I want simple join for

a) Values that are in temp1 and not in temp2
b) Values that are in temp2 and not in temp1

Comment: any keys (primary/foreign) in the tables ?

Comment: No primary/foreign keys in the table

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp Read and find your own solution. If you still couldn't, ask again and also mention the things you tried. You will get better replies.

Comment: How do you decide if the records are not in the other table if you have no primary key?

Comment: You want a `full outer join`: See [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html). Last example

Comment: That's two joins and simple is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well depends on what your match criteria are. This assumes A is a unque id you can use, if not add more to the on clauses.

```
Select 'In Temp1 but not temp2',temp1.*
From Temp1 
Outer Join Temp2 On temp1.A = temp2.A Where temp2.A is null
Union
Select 'In Temp2 but not temp1',temp2.*
From Temp2 
Outer Join Temp1 On temp2.A = temp1.A Where temp1.A is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare all the records on both tables, then you'll need to `JOIN` on all the columns. If you can do something besides a `JOIN`, then I recommend `EXCEPT`:

```
 a):

SELECT *
FROM temp1
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM temp2

 b):

SELECT *
FROM temp2
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM temp1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. it may work for you:

```
select COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3 from TABLE1 where COLUMN1 not in (select COLUMN1  from TABLE2);
```